# flutter app does HTTP GET request only when debuged but not when build

Tags: android, flutter, http-get

Hello Flutter and Android programmers, how are you?

I'm developing an app that makes an HTTP request to download a .json file, then reads it and builds a list of options based on the options available in that file.

When debugging the application with the Flutter hot reload, the application works great, the GET request via HTTP works perfectly, and the list of options is generated perfectly. I am debugging on a physical Android version 11 device, I also tested it on a physical device running Android version 12.

Then, and here is the problem, when I generate my apk with the command

`flutter build apk --release`

And I install it on the same device on which I debugged before, the app doesn't work anymore and stays on the loading screen.

Some solutions that I already tried were:

1- AndroidMainfest.xml permissions:

2- Change the package to make HTTP requests: Previously, I was using the Flutter package

> http.dart

I found as a suggestion to use instead

> dio.dart

But the problem persists.

This are some lines of code that are executed at the moment of the HTTP GET request:

```
void getSongs() async {
    try {
      final dio = Dio();
      final response = await dio
          .get('https://joacoo.pythonanywhere.com/static/json/songs.json');

      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        List<dynamic> jsonResponse = response.data;

        for (int i = 0; i < jsonResponse.length; i++) {
          Song newSong = Song.fromjson(json: jsonResponse[i], id: i);
          songs.add(newSong);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
          String id = songs[i].id.toString();
          String name = songs[i].name;

          songsIDName.add('$id $name');
        }

        songsLoaded = true;
        notifyListeners();
      } else {
        throw Exception('Failed to load songs');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      songsLoaded = true;
    }
  }
```

Then the Song.fromjson(json, id) function is a factory of the Song class:

```
  factory Song.fromjson({required dynamic json, required int id}) {
    String nameFromJson = removeASCIIChars(str: json['name'].toString());
    String categoryFromJson =
        removeASCIIChars(str: json['category'].toString());

    return Song(
      name: nameFromJson,
      category: categoryFromJson,
      bpm: json['bpm'],
      tab: json['tab'],
      id: id,
    );
  }
```

And finally, the function called removeASCIIChars is to handle the ñ issue because the title of the songs are in spanish.

But let me clarify again, all these methods work perfectly in the debug, but not in the release.

Does anyone know why this happens?